# System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize

Tags: c#, serialization, salesforce

Get Error in **System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize** this XML file receive form Salesfroce and exception occurs in binding.Query() method.

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 
                        xmlns='urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
                        xmlns:sf='urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com'>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <queryResponse>
                                <result>
                                    <done>true</done>
                                    <queryLocator xsi:nil='true'/>
                                    <records xsi:type='sf:Contact_Transaction__c'>
                                        <sf:Id xsi:nil='true'/>
                                        <sf:Is_in_SLA__c>Yes</sf:Is_in_SLA__c>
                                    </records>
                                    <records xsi:type='sf:Contact_Transaction__c'>
                                        <sf:Id xsi:nil='true'/>
                                        <sf:Is_in_SLA__c>Yes</sf:Is_in_SLA__c>
                                    </records>
                                </result>
                            </queryResponse>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Upper XML Document is soap responcemessage that receives from salesforce while getting a custom object data. this XML message is a valid XML message .
If i tried manually to  Deserialize a object using deserlization  method then also get XML inner Document error

**My complete Stack Trace**::
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +9416251
   System.Double.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) +36
   System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDouble(String s) +99
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSforceService.Read16_NullableOfDouble(Boolean checkType) +146
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSforceService.Read511_Contact_Transaction__c(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) +9903
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSforceService.Read579_sObject(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) +8124
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSforceService.Read14_QueryResult(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) +1855
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSforceService.Read722_queryResponse() +594
   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer111.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader) +75
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) +130

[InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 461).]
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) +630
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle) +33
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) +1007
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) +221

Comment: You need to add more information than what you have done how is anyone suppose to help you when you don't add any code or what your existing XML looks like good luck

Comment: What is your inner document error?

Comment: Error Message such as:: There is an error in XML document  (inner Document Error ) thanks for help.

Comment: Check the InnnerException, there will be the specific error (keep opening the InnerException of the InnerException till it is null to find the erroneous field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your model object "queryResponse", it seams that a field of type Double can not be setted, becasuse the value received has not a valid format. May be that the value is null (nil='true') and the field is not nullable.

Comment: My field (Is_in_SLA) recordtype is in salesforce Formula (Text) Is there any way to get such field and how to format so i amn't get this exception? thanks for help.